# AWS Lambda how to explain sudden high duration (same code)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I've noticed something weird that I can reproduce with AWS Lambda.

1. I Create a Lambda function (Node.JS 20, x86_64, 128MB)
2. I don't change the default code of the lambda which is the following:

```js
export const handler = async (event) => {
  // TODO implement
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
  };
  return response;
};
```

3. I am then invoking the Lambda function every 5 seconds manually in the console (with the default test payload)

Here is the result (in the right order)

Duration: 14.49 ms  Billed Duration: 15 ms Init Duration: 136 ms
Duration: 7.22 ms   Billed Duration: 8 ms
Duration: 135.23 ms Billed Duration: **136 ms** 
Duration: 142.05 ms Billed Duration: **143 ms** 
Duration: 1.24 ms   Billed Duration: 2 ms
Duration: 1.21 ms   Billed Duration: 2 ms
Duration: 1.23 ms   Billed Duration: 2 ms

Why is there 2 consecutive calls with a significant high duration (136 and 143) ? 
Is it specific to NodeJS ?

Comment: Do you tried using [AWS X-Ray](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-xray.html) to identify potential causes?

Comment: I have turned on XRAY on the Lambda to test.
From the XRAY trace, the high duration is entirely in "Invocation" (not in "overhead").

Comment: Are you using any [Lambda extensions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-extensions.html) here? And you're 100% sure that the only code being invoked is that response definition and the return statement? If you can easily repro this, could you temporarily increase the configured RAM to 1024 MB to see what impact it has, running the same repro test.

Comment: I am not using any Lambda extensions.
Yes 100% sure.

With 1024MB of RAM, there is no issue any longer (that behavior is gone)

Comment: I'd read [Memory configurations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/operatorguide/configurations.html#memory-config), compare the actual cost of running at 1024 MB vs 128 MB (they might be closer than you think), and consider a quick test with [ARM64](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/foundation-arch.html#foundation-arch-adv) at 128MB.